# How to fully display login page with Helix3 on mobile devices?

Tags: login, helix3

When I switched from Gantry to Helix3, two problems arose:

1. On the website, I have a closed page that requires a password. A
   sign in Gantry came in, but in Helix3 there is an error message:

   > "You are not authorized to view this page"
2. In Gantry, the pages
   could appear on tablet and smartphone. In Helix3 there is only a
   part of it that appears and they can not be moved.

Is there a solution? (ie besides returning to Gantry!)

Comment: Are you able to add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you set "Public" for your pages, some case you set only admin login, so this warning is appeared.
2. Can you send me URL? So, I can help. Look like it's just CSS problem.

Comment: Please ensure that you post answers when you have a confident solution to offer.  When you are not confident about your "solution" this is usually a symptom of an Unclear question.  When you need to know more details about the issue, ask for clarification as a comment under the question.  (Of course, you don't yet have enough rep points to comment, so the advice of this community is for you to post answers on answers that are sufficiently clear so that you can earn the necessary amount of rep and become a more effective volunteer.)  Thank you for your contributions.